# how to filter open file dialog in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

How do I filter file types in open - save file dialog with these types?
I want to list all files **EXCLUDING** *JAR and *JAVA
example I found on google:

```
 Using O As New OpenFileDialog With {.Filter = "(Image Files)|*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif;*.ico|Jpg, | *.jpg|Png, | *.png|Bmp, | *.bmp|Gif, | *.gif|Ico | *.ico", .Multiselect = False, .Title = "Select Image"}
     If O.ShowDialog = 1 Then
         TextBox1.Text = O.FileName
     End If
End Using
```

Comment: Did you try the example?  Did it work?  If it didn't, did it throw an error?

Comment: it works, but the example is for filtering images files, but what i want is: Display all file types without *.JAR *.JAVA

Comment: That's not how filters work.  The best you can do is implement the FileOk event and reject files you don't like.  Or organize your directories better.

Comment: @Hans Passant, could you show me how to reject files with            if O.ShowDialog = ?

Comment: Use AddHandler O.FileOk, AddressOf YourMethod

Comment: [FileDialog.FileOk Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.fileok.aspx)

Comment: i just had to double check but you probably want something like `If DirectCast(sender, OpenFileDialog).FileName.ToLower.EndsWith(".jar") Then e.Cancel = True` inside of the `FileOk` Event.

Answer (score 5):

hi you can try this code.

```
openFD.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
openFD.Title = "Open a Text File"
openFD.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt"
openFD.ShowDialog()
```

feel free to contact if get problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There no excluding option in those filters.
You might add code later not to process something if its file type ends with xxxxx 
(whatver you want to exclude).